# API call with saga not returning user data

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-saga

I'm having a lot of issues with this. I've been trying to wire up redux-saga to fetch the user data from the server by calling 'api/current_user'. When I call this API without using saga I get the correct user data, but when I call within saga I get the error message `{error: "Please Log In to Continue"}` meaning the server does not think I am logged in.

I use a passport/express session on the back end to authenticate the user if it matters.

saga.js

```
function* login() {
    try {
        const response = yield fetch(`${API_URL}/api/current_user`, {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
        });
        const responseBody = yield response.json();
        // console.log(r, 'RESPONSE')

        setSession(responseBody);
        yield put(loginUserSuccess(responseBody));
    } catch (error) {
        let message;
        switch (error.status) {
            case 500:
                message = 'Internal Server Error';
                break;
            case 401:
                message = 'Invalid credentials';
                break;
            default:
                message = error;
        }
        yield put(loginUserFailed(message));
        setSession(null);
    }
}
```

working api call page/ button to call saga

```
const AnalyticsDashboardPage = () => {
    const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
    useEffect(() => {
        API.getUser().then((r) => {
            // console.log(r);
            setUser(r);
        });
    }, []);
    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <div className="page-title-box">
                        <div className="page-title-right">
                            <form className="form-inline">
                                <div className="form-group">
                                    <HyperDatepicker />
                                </div>
                                <button className="btn btn-primary ml-2">
                                    <i className="mdi mdi-autorenew"></i>
                                </button>
                                <button className="btn btn-primary ml-1">
                                    <i className="mdi mdi-filter-variant"></i>
                                </button>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                        <h4 className="page-title">Dashboard</h4>
                    </div>
                </Col>
            </Row>
            <Row>
                <Col>
                    <h4>User Data</h4>
                    <pre>{user ? JSON.stringify(user, ' ', 2) : null}</pre>
                    <Button>Login</Button>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    console.log(state);
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { loginUser })(AnalyticsDashboardPage);
```

route I am calling

```
  app.get('/api/current_user', requireLogin, (req, res) => {
    res.send(req.user);
  });
```

requireLogin middleware

```
module.exports = (req, res, next) => {
  if (!req.user) {
    return res.status(401).send({ error: 'You must log in!' });
  }
  next();
};
```

auth reducer

```
const Auth = (state: State = INIT_STATE, action: AuthAction) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOGIN_USER:
            return { ...state, loading: true };
        case LOGIN_USER_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, user: action.payload, loading: false, error: null };
        case LOGIN_USER_FAILED:
            return { ...state, error: action.payload, loading: false };
        case REGISTER_USER:
            return { ...state, loading: true };
        case REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, user: action.payload, loading: false, error: null };
        case REGISTER_USER_FAILED:
            return { ...state, error: action.payload, loading: false };
        case LOGOUT_USER:
            return { ...state, user: null };
        case FORGET_PASSWORD:
            return { ...state, loading: true };
        case FORGET_PASSWORD_SUCCESS:
            return { ...state, passwordResetStatus: action.payload, loading: false, error: null };
        case FORGET_PASSWORD_FAILED:
            return { ...state, error: action.payload, loading: false };
        default:
            return { ...state };
    }
};
```

action

```
export const loginUser = (payload): AuthAction => ({
    type: LOGIN_USER,
    payload,
});
```

Comment: is it possible for u put in codesandbox or stackblitz ?

Answer (score 0):

you need to yield the fetch call itself. as it is a asynchronous operation.
something like this:

```
import { call, put } from 'redux-saga/effects'

function* login() {
    try {
        const response = yield call(fetch,`${API_URL}/api/current_user`, {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
        });
        const responseBody = yield call(response.json);
        // console.log(r, 'RESPONSE')

        setSession(responseBody);
        yield put(loginUserSuccess(responseBody));
    } catch (error) {
        let message;
        switch (error.status) {
            case 500:
                message = 'Internal Server Error';
                break;
            case 401:
                message = 'Invalid credentials';
                break;
            default:
                message = error;
        }
        yield put(loginUserFailed(message));
        setSession(null);
    }
}
```

`response.json` also returns a promise, so you might need to yield it as well.

more details here: https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/basics/UsingSagaHelpers.html

Comment: just tried it with 1 and both yields, but am still having the same issue. I am getting a response from node, but it is saying that I am logged out

Comment: in that case you might be missing some auth token or something from your request parameters. try this approach with some simpler API which just returns some data so that you know this part is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `yield' for any async call.

```
function* login() {
    try {
        const response = yield fetch(`${API_URL}/api/current_user`, {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
        });
        const responseBody = yield response.json();
        // console.log(r, 'RESPONSE')

        setSession(responseBody);
        yield put(loginUserSuccess(responseBody));
    } catch (error) {
        // .....
    }
```

Comment: just tried it with 1 and both yields, but am still having the same issue. I am getting a response from node, but it is saying that I am logged out

Comment: Did you check if try block is getting executed with console.log?